# How to check if a radio button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, click

My code looks like this:

```
form action="familytree.php" method="post">
<?php
foreach ($spouses as $spouse) {
    if (!empty($spouse['mname'])) {
        $name = $spouse['fname'].' '.$spouse['lname'].' ('.$spouse['mname'].')';
    }
    else {
            $name = $spouse['fname'].' '.$spouse['lname'];
    }
    if ($spouse['ended'] == '1') {
        $married = '';
        $divorced = 'checked';
    }
    else {
        $married = 'checked';
        $divorced = '';
    }
    ?>
    <div class="form_section dates">
        <h3><?php echo $name; ?></h3>
        <p>
        <input type="radio" id="married_option" name="married_divorced_options" <?php echo $married; ?> value="1"/>
        <label for="edate">Married</label>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  
        <input type="radio" id="divorced_option" name="married_divorced_options" <?php echo $divorced; ?> value="1"/>
        <label for="sdate">Divorced</label> 
        </p>
        <div class="half" style="display: inline">
            <input type="text" name="sdate_<?php echo $spouse['individual_id']?>" id="sdate_<?php echo $spouse['individual_id']?>" value="<?php echo $spouse['start_date']; ?>" placeholder="Rašykite sutuoktuvių datą čia"/>
            <?php echo $this->formError->error("sdate_".$spouse['individual_id'].""); ?>
        </div>
        <div id="divorced" class="half" style="display:none">
            <input type="text" name="edate_<?php echo $spouse['individual_id']?>" id="edate_<?php echo $spouse['individual_id']?>" value="<?php echo $spouse['end_date']; ?>" placeholder="Rašykite skyrybų datą čia"/>
            <?php echo $this->formError->error("edate_".$spouse['individual_id'].""); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <p class="submit">
        <input class="first-btn" type="submit" id="edit-relationship" name="edit-relationship" value="Edit"/>&nbsp;
    </p>
    </form>
jQuery("#divorced_option").click(function() {
   document.getElementById("divorced").style.display = "inline-block";
});
jQuery("#married_option").click(function() {
   document.getElementById("divorced").style.display = "none";
});
```

What I would like to know is how to check if a radio button is clicked when you don't know its full name, only half of it. For example, `#divorced_option` is not full name, it should be something like this `#divorced_option_161, #divorced_option_161...` So, the code should check if the radio button that has `divorced_option` in its name is clicked. Is there a way to achieve this?

EDIT
It works with `jQuery("[id^='married_option']").click(function(){})`. But I forgot to mention in my original question that the element divorced isn't full name as well, it should be divorced_161, divorced_162, depending of the name of the radio button that is clicked. How can I hide the element that matches with the radio button?

Comment: in its name or in its id?

Comment: @AndrewNewby: First word in the code is `jQuery`, so probably a safe bet.

Comment: why not use "class" attribute for all of them? (because the id is dynamic)

Comment: show some html. Or even a jsfiddle

Comment: @cookiemonster - haha how did I miss that!!!!! Long day :) The other comment stands though - a bit more HTML would help.

Comment: Added more code and it's the name if the id.

Comment: Can you show the (relevant) *rendered* html, rather than the php that generates it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) (ex. `[name^="value"]`):

```
jQuery("[id^='divorced_option']").click(function() {
   document.getElementById("divorced").style.display = "inline-block";
});
jQuery("[id^='married_option']").click(function() {
   document.getElementById("divorced").style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: and maybe use `$('#divorced').show() / hide()` too? ;)

Comment: Thank you, it works. But I forgot to mention in my question that the element divorced isn't full name as well, it should be divorced_161, divorced_162, depending of the name of the radio button that is clicked. How can I hide the element that matches with the radio button?

Comment: Just use `this` or `$(this)` inside the click handler if it should refer to the element being clicked.

Comment: @j08691, the problem is that the element clicked is not the element that should be hidden.

Comment: So how should the element being clicked know which element should be hidden? What's the relation?

Comment: @j08691, the word divorced and number after the dash.

Comment: So clicking `#divorced_option_161` should change the display of `#divorced_161`?

Comment: @j08691, yes it should.

Comment: Anyway, you answered my original question and it helped a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

The '[Attribute Contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)' selector would be useful here, which means your code would be :

```
jQuery("[id*='divorced_option']").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("divorced").style.display = "inline-block";
});
jQuery("[id*='married_option']").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("divorced").style.display = "none";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the elements based on the `#divorced_option_[number]` pattern while checking if they are selected like this:

```
$("input[id*=divorced_option]:checked");
```

If you would like to check wether the `divorced_option` substring is in the `name=""` attribute of the radio element, then change the `id` from the selector to `name`, like so:

```
$("input[name*=divorced_option]:checked");
```

After this, just check wether or not jQuery returned an actual element.